# javac does not compile the Java code even though the jars are present and available

Tags: java, windows, classpath

I am trying to compile a Java source file on command prompt with the following command

```
C:\temp\test>javac -cp ".\*;"  *.java
```

but the class does not get compiles, I have errors of type files not found, or could not find resource.

Even though the jars are present in the same directory as the Java files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C:\temp\test>javac -cp ".;*.jar" *.java

See http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to forget that a `.jar` file is a compressed file system structure, not a `.class` file. When you specify a directory in `-classpath`, all `.class` files in that directory are available to the loader. Specifying a `.jar` file is analogous to specifying a directory, but in addition to the `.class` files in the `.jar` file's root directory, it also makes available `.class` files in the **packages** compressed into the `.jar` structure. Remember that the package structure mirrors a directory structure.